# Why doesn't this awk code do what I want it to do?

Tags: awk

I have this file:

```
$ head -n 4 badRegionFromHWE.merged
seqnames start end width strand
chr1 144118070 145868461 1750392 *
chr7 100049516 101110026 1060511 *
chr7 141508887 142999071 1490185 *
$
```

I want to not print out the header line and print column 1,2,3 separated by tabs. So I wrote this:

```
awk 'OFS="\t";NR>1{print$1,$2,$3}' badRegionFromHWE.merged | head
seqnames start end width strand
chr1 144118070 145868461 1750392 *
chr1    144118070   145868461
chr7 100049516 101110026 1060511 *
chr7    100049516   101110026
chr7 141508887 142999071 1490185 *
chr7    141508887   142999071
```

It doesn't do what I wanted it to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment `OFS="\t"` evaluates to true (non-zero, non-empty) on every line, so it prints every line.  You should enclose the expression in a BEGIN block:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t" } NR > 1 { print$1, $2, $3 }' badRegionFromHWE.merged
```